# Request object recognized as a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, sidekiq

My request object for my sidekiq worker is being recognized as a string.

application_controller.rb

```
  def log_variant
    @request = request
    AnalyticsWorker.perform_async(@request)
  end
```

variant_worker.rb

```
class VariantWorker

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(current_request)
    variant = current_request.variant.join
    puts variant
  end  
end
```

Here is the error

```
undefined method `variant' for "#<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000101b83510>":String
```

I'm storing the request object in an instance variable so I should be able to call the variant method on it yes? Is the request object too complex to perform this sidekiq operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the background, Sidekiq is serializing that parameter into Redis. I'm guessing Redis is casting it down to a string. In general, you want to pass minimal data in that parameter as noted [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices).